# Existence of random variable given infinite-dimensional probability measure

Tags: probability-theory

Let $\mathcal{X}$ be some possibly infinite-dimensional metric space and let $\mu$ be a Borel probability measure on $\mathcal{X}$.

What theorem implies the existence of a probability space $(\Omega, \mathbb{F}, P)$ and a random variable $X: \Omega \to \mathcal{X}$ such that the distribution of $X$ is $\mu$? What conditions are required?

Answer (score 1):

Take $\Omega =\mathcal X $, $\mathbb F=$ Borel sigma algebra, $P=\mu$ and take $X$ to be the identity map.